# Google Search Engine Position Regex

Tags: c#, regex, google-search

Currently my regex in C# is

```
string lookup = "(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\"/url?q=)(\\w+[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-?=/:]*)";
```

I am trying to match google search engine position result which looks like below

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://uk.yahoo.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CBUQFjAAahUKEwi_koaWptjHAhXG8HIKHYcQCl0&amp;usg=AFQjCNHkhixstCvIO45GIKI44_kp6ul36w">
```

This code function more detail

```
string lookup = "(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\"/url?q=)(\\w+[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-?=/:]*)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, lookup);

            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
                string match = matches[i].Groups[2].Value;
                if (match.Contains(url.Host))
                    return i + 1;
            }

            return 0;
```

the error which I am experiencing is I always getting "0"

Comment: Perhaps, when you chose regex to parse HTML? :) Why not using an HTML parser? You can easily get the `href` attribute value of `a` tag that is a child of `h3` tag with `class="r"` with e.g. HtmlAgilityPack, and then check if the value starts with `url?q=`. And then just get your value.

Comment: What does not working entail? what is it matching / not matching that it should do?

Comment: @stribizhev i am quite new to HTML parser so I will check that out too

Comment: @Sayse i have added more code which should explain what trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with [HtmlAgilityPack HTML parser](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (install it using *Manage NuGet Packages for Solution* from the drop-down menu when right-clicking the solution name in the Solution explorer):

```
var html = "<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\"/url?q=https://uk.yahoo.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CBUQFjAAahUKEwi_koaWptjHAhXG8HIKHYcQCl0&amp;usg=AFQjCNHkhixstCvIO45GIKI44_kp6ul36w\">";
var tags_with_attributes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>();
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
Uri uriResult;
if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
{ // html is a URL 
   var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
   hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
}
else
{ // html is a string
   hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
   hap.LoadHtml(html);
}
var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3/a[@href]");
if (nodes != null)
{
   foreach (var node in nodes)
   {
       foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes)
          if (attribute.Name == "href" && attribute.Value.StartsWith("/url?q="))
            Console.WriteLine(attribute.Value.Substring(7));
    }
}
```

This will parse Web page if use an URL in `html`, or a HTML string.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with the regex above is that you forgot to escape `?`

```
string lookup = "(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\"/url\\?q=)(\\w+[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-?=/:]*)";
```

I'm not sure if the regex returns what you want, because I wasn't able to understand what you are trying to match from your description. But for sure unexcaped `"?"` is a problem.

Comment: Also I agree with stribizhev that it's much simpler if you use AgilityPack.

Comment: I do not say "simpler", but "safer" - yes.

Comment: @MaticDiba excellent thanks for pointing out your solution works and in mean time I will check html parser more too.